# JApplet, client/server program

Tags: java, sockets, japplet

I am trying to create a a simple client/server program within a JApplet. 
 When I run the program a connection is made, however the applet does not start and on the JApplet it says 'applet loaded' but does not say 'applet started'.  The problem is that if I want to do other things (other than create a connection) within the applet I can't because the applet has not started.

```
public class Frame extends JApplet {

Socket s;
ObjectInputStream in;
String serverIP = "127.0.0.1";
int serverPortNo = 9011;

public void init(){

    try{
        s = new Socket(serverIP, serverPortNo);
        setupConnection();
    }
    catch(IOException e){
        System.out.println("error : "+ e.getMessage());
    }

}

public void setupConnection(){
    try{
        in = new ObjectInputStream(s.getInputStream());
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());

    }
}
}
```

Server class.

```
public class Server {

ServerSocket ss;

public Server(int port){

    try{
        ss = new ServerSocket(port);
        acceptConnections();
    }
    catch(IOException e){
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}

public void acceptConnections(){
    Socket s;
    System.out.println("acc");

    int playerID = 0;
    while(true){
        try{
            System.out.println("waiting for connections");
            s= ss.accept();
            System.out.println("connection");

        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("error : " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Before you waste more time, you should switch from `JApplet` to a normal desktop application using `JFrame`. Applets are a dead technology which you missed by about half a dozen years or so. Considering that they're no longer supported by modern browsers, you really don't want to continue down that path.

Comment: Ok thanks, so how would I intergrate a java application into a website ?

Comment: You wouldn't. Depending on what you're trying to do, you might create a solution that uses a Java backend, a Javascript frontend and uses websockets for communication. This could be used to implement for example a traditional multi-user chatroom.